# Why is minidlna closing connections with clients?

Tags: nixos, dlna

OS: NixOS unstable
App: [minidlna](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-unstable/pkgs/tools/networking/minidlna/default.nix#L33)

I used minidlna successfully with Debian and my TV. But I am having problems with NixOS.

This is my NixOS config (`/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`):

```
#DLNA
services.minidlna.enable = true;
services.minidlna.settings = {
  friendly_name = "PCMEDIA";
  media_dir = ["V,/mnt/ORION/DLNA/"];
  log_level = "debug";
};
```

This is the log when I try to connect to the DLNA server with my TV:

```
$ sudo journalctl --unit minidlna -r
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: EXT:
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: Date: Sat, 06 May 2023 02:38:54 GMT
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: Server: 5.15.93 DLNADOC/1.50 UPnP/1.0 MiniDLNA/1.3.1
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: Content-Length: 2196
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: Connection: close
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: upnphttp.c:1277: debug: HTTP RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: 
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: X-PANASONIC-DMP-Profile: MPEG_PS_PAL JPEG_SM PV_DIVX_DIV3 PV_DIVX_DIV4 PV_DIVX_DIVX PV_DIVX_DX50 PV_DRM_DIVX_DIV3 PV_DRM_DIVX_DIV4 PV_DRM_DIVX_DIVX P>
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: X-PANASONIC-Registration: (hexadecimal number)
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: Host: 192.168.1.180:8200
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: User-Agent: Panasonic MIL DLNA CP UPnP/1.0 DLNADOC/1.50
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: upnphttp.c:916: debug: HTTP REQUEST: GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: clients.c:357: debug: Client found in cache. [Panasonic/entry 0]
May 06 08:08:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: minidlna.c:170: debug: HTTP connection from 192.168.1.184:58601
May 06 08:08:53 nixos minidlnad[40642]: minissdp.c:710: debug: SSDP M-SEARCH from 192.168.1.184:50051 ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:2, MX: 1, MAN: "ssdp:discover"
May 06 08:08:53 nixos minidlnad[40642]: minissdp.c:710: debug: SSDP M-SEARCH from 192.168.1.184:50051 ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:2, MX: 1, MAN: "ssdp:discover"
May 06 08:08:53 nixos minidlnad[40642]: minissdp.c:265: debug: Sending M-SEARCH response to 192.168.1.184:50050 ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:
May 06 08:08:53 nixos minidlnad[40642]: minissdp.c:710: debug: SSDP M-SEARCH from 192.168.1.184:50050 ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1, MX: 1, MAN: "ssdp:discover"
May 06 08:08:53 nixos minidlnad[40642]: minissdp.c:265: debug: Sending M-SEARCH response to 192.168.1.184:50050 ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:
May 06 08:08:53 nixos minidlnad[40642]: minissdp.c:710: debug: SSDP M-SEARCH from 192.168.1.184:50050 ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1, MX: 1, MAN: "ssdp:discover"
May 06 08:07:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: <root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0"><specVersion><major>1</major><minor>0</minor></specVersion><device><deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:dev>
May 06 08:07:54 nixos minidlnad[40642]: <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

How to make minidlna work? Not just my TV, it doesn't work with VLC or any other DLNA capable application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`minidlna` cannot access the "media directories" specified. NixOS runs `minidlna` as the user `minidlna`. So the user `minidlna` needs to be added to a user group that has access to the locations specified in the media directories.

`/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:`

```
services.minidlna.enable = true;
services.minidlna.settings = {
  friendly_name = "Movies";
  media_dir = ["V,/mnt/ORION/DLNA/"];

  # so changes in media dirs are updates in the server listing
  # also make sure "inotify-tools" packages is installed
  inotify = "yes"; 
  #log_level = "debug";
};

users.users.minidlna = {
  extraGroups = [ "users" ];
};
```

Also if you tried to run `minidlna` as a system user you might want to clear out `/var/cache/minidlna` or the `db_dir` in general.

Answer (score 2):

Check the name and permissions of `/mnt/ORION/DLNA/` with something like `ls -ld /mnt/ORION/DLNA`.

Also, instead of

```
media_dir = ["V,/mnt/ORION/DLNA/"];
```

try

```
media_dir = V,/mnt/ORION/DLNA
```

(no brackets, no quotes and no trailing slash as per [the manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/minidlna/minidlna.conf.5.en.html)) since otherwise you might end up without valid paths, and that could a reason for the early close.

Comment: Your response sent me in the right direction. The issue is indeed about permissions.